# Implementing Monad#compose

Tags: scala

[Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/) shows this [implementation](https://github.com/pchiusano/fpinscala/blob/7b962343a977d59e63d315b9622ac060203f643b/answerkey/monads/9.answer.scala) of `compose`:

```
def compose[A, B, C](f: A => F[B], g: B => F[C]): A => F[C] = {
    a => flatMap(f(a))(g)
}
```

How can I understand the `a` in front of `=>`?

Comment: Try to keep in mind the return type: `A => F[C]`. Not sure what else to say...

Comment: `compose` is a function that returns another function. `a` is the parameter this returned function takes.

Comment: understood, @IonuțG.Stan. I wasn't used to seeing `return types` as a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 6.23 of the spec on anonymous functions, it says you can omit types of the params if the expected type is a function (from which the compiler can infer the param types).

The expected type here is the result type `A => F[C]`, so `a` is an `A`.

And with that, I'm not sure what else to say either...